# UILabel not visually refreshing

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uilabel

### The Problem

I have a `UILabel` buried in a few layers of subviews and I can't seem to change it's text. The code to update the label is in`MyCardSubclass`'s `updateVisualElements` method. The really weird thing is that **when I log the description of these labels, the text has been updated, but it is not visible.** Here's what it looks like:

Inside my View Controller's `viewDidLoad` method I initialize a `UIScrollView` and my card object. I add its `cardView` as a subview like so:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    MyCardSubclass *myCard = [[MyCardSubclass alloc]initWithInfo:info andPoint:CGPointMake(5, runningYValue)];
    [myCard setParentViewController:self];
    [scrollView addSubview:[myCard cardView]];

    //Resize scrollView contentSize
}
```

#### My Card

```
//header
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *contentView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *cardView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CardInfo *cardInfo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *parentViewController;

//implementaion
-(UIView *)cardView
{
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
UIView *toReturn = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.point.x,self.point.y, screenRect.size.width-borderOffset*2, cardViewHeight)];

UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(borderOffset, 0, toReturn.frame.size.width-borderOffset*2, titleHeight)];
[titleLabel setText:self.title];
[toReturn addSubview:titleLabel];

[self.contentView setFrame:CGRectMake(borderOffset, titleHeight, screenRect.size.width-borderOffset, contentViewHeight)];
if(self.contentView)
    [toReturn addSubview:self.contentView];
else
    NSLog(@"no contentView");

//other view stuff

return toReturn;
}
```

#### My Card Subclass

```
//header
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *totalAmountLabel;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UILabel *availableAmountLabel;
@property(nonatomic, assign) double available;

//implementation
-(UIView *)cardView
{
  [self setContentView:[self contentViewFromCardInfo:self.cardInfo]];
  return [super cardView];
}

-(UIView *)contentViewFromCardInfo:(CardInfo *)cardInfo
{
  UIView *toReturn = [[UIView alloc]init];

  NSString *amount = @"0";

  self.totalAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(labelWidth,
                                                                     runningYValue,
                                                                     labelWidth,
                                                                     labelHeight)];
  [self.totalAmountLabel setText:amount];
  [toReturn addSubview:self.totalAmountLabel];
  runningYValue +=self.totalAmountLabel.frame.size.height+spacer;

  self.availableAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(labelWidth,
                                                                         runningYValue,
                                                                         labelWidth,
                                                                         labelHeight)];


  [self.availableAmountLabel setText:@"0"];
  [toReturn addSubview:self.availableAmountLabel];

  return toReturn;
}

-(void)updateVisualElements
{
  NSString *amount = @"10"
  NSString *availableString = @100"
  //The log descriptions for these labels are okay.
  [self.totalAmountLabel setText:amount];
  NSLog(@"%@",self.totalAmountLabel.debugDescription);
  [self.availableAmountLabel setText:availableString];
  NSLog(@"%@",self.availableAmountLabel.debugDescription);

  NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"Not on main thread");
  NSAssert(self.totalAmountLabel, @"No label");
}
```

### What I've tried

- Calling `[self.totalAmountLabel setNeedsDisplay]` after setting the text
- Calling the method on the main thread using `[self.totalAmountLabel performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:amount afterDelay:0.0]`

Comment: Where is updateVisualElements getting called from?  I don't see it getting called.

Comment: I didn't include that section, but after I receive a notification, I dismiss a modal view controller and then call updateVisualElements

Comment: I'm just confirming, do you see the NSLog statements from updateVisualElements printing out?  I'm really trying to verify that the method is definitely getting called?

Comment: Yes, I can verify that these logs are printing and the method is definitely getting called.

Comment: How about the label's initial values?  Before you change the text, can you see the initial values in the UI?  Set the text to something distinctive in IB, and see if you see that, first.  If you don't, that's a big clue.

Comment: Yes, I can successfully log the existing text of the label before attempting to set it in the updateVisualElements method. And I have not used IB to create any part of my views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! The problem wasn't actually in my attempts to set the label or draw its view.

I wasn't using my initializers properly to init my content view only once.

I removed this override in my subclass

```
-(UIView *)cardView
{
  [self setContentView:[self contentViewFromCardInfo:self.cardInfo]];
  return [super cardView];
}
```

I also took the code from the `-(UIView *)cardView` method in my superclass and put into a `-(UIView *)buildCardView` method and rewrote the cardView property accessor to what it should have been.

```
-(UIView *)cardView
{
    if(!_cardView)
        _cardView = [self buildCardView];

    return _cardView;
}
```

Thanks for the views and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one thing, Use **`Tag`** property to get the added Label and change its contends

**Example:**

```
   UILabel totalAmountLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(labelWidth,
                                                                     runningYValue,
                                                                     labelWidth,

  [totalAmountLabel setText:amount];
  totalAmountLabel.tag = 100;
  [toReturn addSubview:totalAmountLabel];
```

Then in your **`updateVisualElements()`**

```
 UILabel *tempTotalAmountLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:100];
 [tempTotalAmountLabel setText:amount];
```